# How to connect a React app with aframe VR app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe

I have a React app where a user is making configurations for the VR part of the app which is built with [a-frame](https://aframe.io/).

After the selection and configuration is done in the React part, the a-frame VR part should be shown with the specific configuration.

What is the best way to connect those two parts?

I already know about [`aframe-react`](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-react), but I'm not sure if it reduces the performance of the app a lot.

Comment: I've built VR apps with a-frame and React using the `aframe-react` package. Performance has not been an issue, so I suggest you just try it out and start optimizing when necessary. Also read this somewhat related article about premature optimization: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's A-Frame React, yeah.

Or you could use raw DOM / A-Frame and pass and pass all data as strings, which is fine, just like HTML.

The performance is an issue if you route all the logic through React, if you can strictly separate the React layer and the A-Frame layer, should be good.

Comment: hi Kevin, on the aframe-react github page, u dont recommend using aframe-react. Will aframe-react not be supported in the future?

If using the alternative approaches u mentioned, are there any sample codes we can refer to for ya recommended approaches to use with React?

Im currently deciding which approach to adopt to implement a 360 pano image. If using react-vr, it seems my vr will need to be a standalone site. Ya solution allows me to create a full stack app however, im concerned if i use aframe-react to build, the tooling will not be supported down the road

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I would not use React at all for anything VR. aframe-react may dwindle as I don't use it myself, but it's already complete (it's a very thin bridge). You can just use A-Frame by itself, it works great. I've adopted React/Vue patterns into stuff like https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-state-component

Comment: Thanks Kevin for y clarification. Appreciate

Comment: Hi kevin, using aframe state component, it cant be used with react right? It needs to be vanilla html n js? If can use with react, is there any boilerplate code i can refer? Apologies, i looked at d link ya sent but cant seem to make sense how to integrate it with react or vue

Comment: Btw its a waste if aframe react dwindles. I searched d web for vr info n must say its an excellent tooling. React vr needs to be used alone and cant be integrated with React for a full stack app which react aframe can. Unfortunately my programming skill is not at a high level yet otherwise i could join u guys in maintaining it. If ever u all looking for someone in ya team to help maintain (take note im not at such a high level as u guys), i ll b open :)

Comment: It might seem nice coming from a webdev world, but it's an anti-pattern for VR. It's not that we can't maintain it, it's that it's a bad idea to use React for VR apps. It adds perf overhead, complexity, and devs usually mishandle it (putting critical 3D/VR logic in the React level). I mentioned the state component adopts patterns from React/Vue, not integrates with them. But that component could work with aframe-react, yeah, but doesn't make sense much.

Comment: Ic Kevin. Thanks for the advice